# Error processing request: Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Tags: magento-1.9, php

We're on Magento 1.9. Our website is displaying an error: There has been an error processing your request.

please give the solution..[image]

Comment: check error details in var/report/

Comment: then display the report file on  =>   a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted";i:1;s:2842:"#0 /home/happyshc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(777): Zend_Uri::factory('shopping/')
#1 /home/happyshc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(611): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home/happyshc/public_html/app/Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)

Comment: added answer please check

Comment: Take the trailing slash off of the value in design/themes/skin and you should be golden.

Answer (score 1):

Check your url in core_config_data table

> Make sure the base_url is a valid URI Schema, so it should be like
>   http://magento/ Afterwards clear your cache and the issue should be
>   solved.

Comment: The base_url is ok and everything is ok. But i dont find about the error.

Comment: check both web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url  in core_config_data table

Comment: both are as same as good. I was check it and rename local.xml.sampl to local.xml

Comment: errors/local.xml.sample ? That will just print error on same page

Comment: paste your both base_url here

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url        =>  http://happyshopee.com/
web/secure/base_url            =>  http://happyshopee.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30373/discussion-between-east-end-and-minesh-patel).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30397/discussion-between-east-end-and-minesh-patel).

Answer (score 0):

The error **`Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)`** show that may  be the ***skin url not  set properly set***. You need  to check ***skin url is properly set of the theme***

Comment: i'll try all the ways. but no result. please anybody can help me